# Proof for sequent in pLJ

Tags: logic

I'm looking for a proof in the extended sequent calculus pLJ+ for the following sequent:

⊢ ¬¬A → A

pLJ+ is pLJ extended with the axiom ⊢ A v ¬A

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

The intuitive argument goes like this:

> Suppose $\neg\neg A$ for the sake of argument.
>
> You have $A \lor \neg A$. So argue by cases (what else?!). The first disjunct gives you $A$ trivially. The second disjunct $\neg A$, together with your supposition,  gives you $\bot$ and hence $A$ (by *ex contradictione quodlibet*). So either way you have $A$.
>
> Now discharge the initial temporary supposition to get $\neg\neg A \to A$.

Now, exercise: massage that intuitive proof idea into sequent calculus form!

Answer (score 1):

I will draft two separate sub-derivations (A) and (B) :

> $A \rightarrow A$ --- *Axiom*
>
> $\lnot \lnot A, A \rightarrow A$ --- *Weakening*-left
>
> > $A \rightarrow \lnot \lnot A \supset A$ --- $\supset$-right --- (A)
>
> $A \rightarrow A$ --- *Axiom*
>
> $\lnot A, A \rightarrow$ --- $\lnot$-left
>
> $\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot A$ --- $\lnot$-right
>
> $\lnot \lnot A , \lnot A \rightarrow$ --- $\lnot$-left
>
> $\lnot \lnot A , \lnot A \rightarrow A$ --- *Weakening*-right
>
> > $\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot \lnot A \supset A$ --- $\supset$-right --- (B)

Now we apply $\lor$-left to (A) and (B) to get :

> $A \lor \lnot A \rightarrow \lnot \lnot A \supset A$

Finally, we apply *Cut* to the last formula with the *axiom* : $\rightarrow A \lor \lnot A$ (used as cut-formula) and we have :

> > $\rightarrow \lnot \lnot A \supset A$